# Requirement for validity of a passport

Tags: passports, passport-renewals, visa-expiration, valid

In several questions, I read that there are additional validity restrictions for the passport if you visit a foreign country: e. g., a country requires that your passport is valid for at least 6 months after your planned departure.

This restriction seems to be imposed by many countries.

What is the background of this requirement? I mean, a valid passport is a valid passport. And as long as my passport is valid, it should be fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think I have to dupe-mark my own question…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you come to **visit** a country, they want to be sure that you can **leave** again. And if you don't want to leave, they want to be sure that they can send you away.

If you have a valid passport, they can send you home more easily. So they want a passport validity for your intended duration of stay, plus some extra. You might get hospitalized, or a volcano disrupts air travel, or whatever. So they tack on some extra time.